# WooCommerce custom code breaks after upgrade to 3.X

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

After the newer release of WooCommerce 3.X , the code written for WoCommerce 2.X doesn't work anymore without throwing error on the product type line.

```
function remove_bundled_items_from_cart( $cart_item_key, $instance ) {

 if ( ! empty( $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key] ) ) {

    $product_id     = $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['product_id'];
    $product_type   = $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['data']->product_type;

    if ( $product_type == 'bundle' ) {
        if (is_array($instance->cart_contents) || is_object($instance->cart_contents)) {
         foreach ( $instance->cart_contents as $key => $cart_item ) {
            if ( isset( $cart_item['is_bundled_item'] ) && $cart_item['is_bundled_item'] == $product_id ) {
                WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $key );
            }
         }
        }
    }
 }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'remove_bundled_items_from_cart', 10, 2 );
```

Does anybody know what I need to change to be able to have the $product_type stop throwing a error?

I would still need to be able to check if the string is "bundle", so I need somehow to get the information fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the main error in your code comes from:

```
$product_type = $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['data']->product_type;
```

> The **`$instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['data']`** is the `WC_Product` Object instance and since WC versions 3+ `WC_Product` properties can't be accessed directly anymore. 
>   Instead you will use the `WC_Product` method [**`get_type()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_type) *(or the conditional method [**`is_type()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_is_type))*…

As **`$instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['data']`** doesn't exist in simple products, you need to test it in your first condition.

This should avoid throwing errors (on the product type line…):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'remove_bundled_items_from_cart', 10, 2 );
function remove_bundled_items_from_cart( $cart_item_key, $instance ) {

     if ( ! empty( $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['data'] ) ) {

        $product_id = $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['product_id'];
        $product    = $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['data']; // The WC_Product object

        if ( $product->is_type( 'bundle' ) ) {
            if (is_array($instance->cart_contents) || is_object($instance->cart_contents)) {
                foreach ( $instance->cart_contents as $key => $cart_item ) {
                    if ( isset( $cart_item['is_bundled_item'] ) && $cart_item['is_bundled_item'] == $product_id ) {
                        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $key );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **BUT I don't see in the raw cart data output any `'is_bundled_item'` key…**
>
> Instead you can use in your code one of this available cart array keys:
>
> - **`bundled_by`** key `(the parent WC_Bundle_Product cart item key)`
> - **`bundled_item_id`** key `(the child bundle item ID)`

So you could replace in your code `'is_bundled_item'` like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'remove_bundled_items_from_cart', 10, 2 );
function remove_bundled_items_from_cart( $cart_item_key, $instance ) {

     if ( ! empty( $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['data'] ) ) {
        $product    = $instance->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['data'];

        if ( $product->is_type( 'bundle' ) ) {
            if (is_array($instance->cart_contents) || is_object($instance->cart_contents)) {
                foreach ( $instance->cart_contents as $key => $cart_item ) {
                    if ( isset( $cart_item['bundled_item_id'] ) && $cart_item['bundled_by'] == $cart_item_key ) {
                        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $key );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should work totally…

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you have a check for product type like this, how should you use is_type?:
`<?php $product_type_label = ( $addon['product']->product_type == 'audio_conference' ) ? 'Recording' : $addon['product']->product_type; ?>`

Comment: @Zhakal You should try to get the raw data for `$addon['product']` this way: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($addon['product']); echo '</pre>';` … So you will e able to see all related data structure and you should see if it's a an extend product type in which you can use WC_Product methods on it (this is just for testing purpose).